# Display heading on element hover

Tags: css, hover

I'm working on [this site](http://mtthwbsh.com/sta499) right now, and my goal is to add the following functionality:

- When hovering over a single image, I want to display a title contained in a heading.
- The interaction should transition from the color bar and have the same background

I'm thinking this is probably achievable with CSS alone, but am having trouble visualize how the markup would work. Any suggestions or points in a direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add a fiddle or code, because soon, you will solve the issue, and then your question will have no historical value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with CSS3. http://jsfiddle.net/zh3EC/

```
a > h3 {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1.5em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #993434;
    padding: 0.4em;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
        transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}

a:hover > h3 {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was getting after, but hadn't seen the method in action before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').hover(function() {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
    }, function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: This will not work, because the only thing you are doing is creating a variable on hover and calling a function that does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `div` with a `background-image` and an `h1` (title) inside with the title; then use the `:hover` pseudoclass to have the opacity change from `0` to `1` for the title.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>Title Here</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-image: url('image_here.jpg');
}

h1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}

p:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GJdMq/2/)